# Browser sync for sublime text on mac is not running when my index.html is selected and I press "launch

Tags: macos, sublimetext3, browser-sync

- I downloaded Node.js
- started up sublime text and used Package Control: install package
- Downloaded browser-sync
- It showed up on the top of the screen in the toolbar area
- Selected Browser Sync and selected my index.html file
- Clicked launch in the Browser Sync toolbar
- Literally nothing happens

Thank you for any suggestions on how to fix this or what I am doing wrong.